# Factory Girl - creating associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've done my best to follow the documentation and similar questions on this site with no joy. I'm trying to create a ceremony, which has many invites:

ceremony.rb

```
class Ceremony < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
end
```

invite.rb

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ceremony
end
```

In my spec I"m trying to create invites related to a ceremony as follows:

```
  let(:ceremony) { FactoryGirl.create(:ceremony) }
  let(:nom_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:nominee, award: award) }
  let(:inv_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:invite, email: nom_1.email, ceremony: ceremony) }
  let(:inv_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:invite, ceremony: ceremony) }
  let(:inv_3) { FactoryGirl.create(:invite, ceremony: ceremony) }
  before do
    User.delete_all
  end
  it 'should return invites not assigned a nominee' do
    binding.pry
    expect(award.available_nominees).to include(inv_2, inv_3)
  end
```

When the test hits binding.pry and I go exploring, I can see a new ceremony has been created, and 3 new invites with that ceremony's ID. When I call

```
ceremony.invites
```

I receive an empty relation. When I call

```
Invite.where(ceremony: ceremony.id)
```

I receive [inv_1, inv_2, inv_3]. When I call

```
inv_1.ceremony
```

I receive the ceremony, however again

```
ceremony.invites
```

returns an empty relation. I'm at a loss why the invites are created with the correct ceremony ID, and yet the ceremony apparently has no invites. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added association with ceremony, when you define your `Invite` factory?

Comment: I don't think I need to as I'm explicitly stating them, but yes I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment of creation of a `ceremony` there are no `invites` in the database. Because Rails caches database queries the `invites` array will stay empty unless:

- You add invites manually: `ceremony.invites = [inv_1, ...]`,
- You add the invites right when creating the `ceremony` (in the factory or when calling the factory) or
- you reload the `ceremony` or its `invites` relation.

I would choose the second option and would add `ceremony.reload` or `ceremony.invites(true)` before calling the expectation.

Comment: Answer was along the right lines. I had to manually call each object before performing the test: before do [inv_1, inv_2, inv_3 etc..]. Then ceremony.reload and it was picking them up.

Comment: Right, you never call `ceremony` in your tests therefore the whole record wasn't generated. You can call each object in a before block, another option is to use `let!` instead of `let` (note the bang).